# Program gives me gigantic number when adding small numbers

Tags: c

I've already searched, but could not quite find my answer.  I'm relatively new to C (in high school), and a problem ALWAYS pops up in any math program I ever write.  I'll have some small numbers and when they are run through, the result is some gigantic number.  I have copied programs off of sites and books, and the same issue occurs.  Here's the source code for one example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int c, k = c + 273;
    printf("Enter your celsius degree here...\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    printf("%d",&k);
}
```

It's a simple code, but still comes out weird.

Comment: You are using `c` before you have assigned a value to it. Since it is an automatic variable it's value will be indeterminate. Move `k = c+273` after the `scanf`. Also, `&k` will return the address of `k` you just want to use `k` in the `printf`.

Comment: There's also no multiplication in the code...

Comment: When you initialize `k = c + 273` the value of c can be ANYTHING because you haven't set it yet.  Instead define k AFTER the scanf call and then c will have a value and k will have the right value.  But your printf isn't printing the value of k - it is printing the ADDRESS of k so you need to say `printf("%d",k);` instead.

Comment: KI am interested in the web site that gives you such code

Comment: Berg, there was multiplication in other examples, this was just one of the many.

Comment: Well, if you actually found this code on a web site, don't visit that web site again.

Comment: The title needs to match the code, otherwise you are likely to receive downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

You never assigned a value to `c` before using it to compute `k`.  So, what you wnat for your code is probably:

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
    int c, k;
    printf("Enter your celsius degree here...\n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    k = c + 273;
    printf("%d",k);
}
```

Notice that when you print, you do not use `&`.  That would be giving the address of `k`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, c is not being initialized. In c, non initialized variables have undefined behavior (garbage) values.

Comment: Don't forget that the printf call is printing the address of k instead of the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int c = 0, k = 0;
k = c +273;
scanf("%d", &c);
printf("%d", k);
```

The initialization of k and c will help remove the garbage values stored in them and you will get the correct output.